# Magento 1.9 - send order admin email to different email address

Tags: email, magento, magento-1.9

I have 10 customer group in my website. I would send the order admin notification email to different address, based on user customer group.

For example.

User from **customer_group_a** take order will send admin notification to **order1@website.com**. Then user from **customer_group_b** take order will send admin notification to **order2@website.com**

Also, how can i get the customer data in order email? I try this, but not working in **email/sales/order_new.html**:

```
{{var customer.name}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send to different people, the best is to add the needed email adressess via system.xml to be able to edit in your back-office the emails then you will need to override `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to fit with your logic. The lines that interest you are in `queueNewOrderEmail()` function.

Try to use the constant for the path to your config.

For the name in your template, you can normally use `{{var order.customer_name}}` if my memory is good or `{{var order.customer.name}}`. The functions `getCustomer()` and `getCustomerName()` exist in the precited class.